# React Native flex and Layout issue

Tags: react-native, android-studio, styles, jsx, picker

I never worked on an app development project before, however since we have no one to make some changes my manager wants me to make those tweaks, so far I've been successful with the help of stock-overflow community but there is few concepts and line of code that I wasn't able to grasp even when searching online and watching YouTube videos.

1- some times a view or text is assigned a predefined style. exp: style={styles.myAndroidStyle}
question: how can I keep this style and charge one parameter only like color for example?

I put all the options I tried in bold.

2- speaking of color, what is the difference between those two ways of assigning color
     color={Colors.myColorGold}
     color: Colors.myColorGold

3-  same thing here, what is the difference between those two ways of navigation 
    this.props.navigation.navigate('NotificationPreferences');
    this.navigate('NotificationPreferences');

4- I have this picker with a place holder, I tried everything to change the color of the place holder without success, any idea?

```
  const MyPicker = ({myOptions, handleChange, selectedID}) => {
    return Platform.OS === 'ios' ? (
        <RNPickerSelect
            placeholder={{label: 'Select an item', value: null, **placeholderTextColor: Colors.myColorGold**}}
            **placeholderTextColor={Colors.myColorGold}**
            items={itemOptions}
            onValueChange={handleChangeItem}
            style={{inputIOS: styles.inputIOS, inputAndroid: styles.inputAndroid, **Color: Colors.myColorGold**}}
            value={selectedItemID}
            **textColor={Colors.myColorGold}**
        />
    ) : (
        <Picker
            selectedValue={selectedItemID}
            style={styles.inputAndroid}
            onValueChange={handleChangeItem}
            **textColor={Colors.myColorGold}**
            **Color={Colors.myColorGold}**

        >
          <Picker.Item  label="Select a item" value="null" **textColor={Colors.myColorGold} Color={Colors.myColorGold}**/>
          {
            ItemOptions.map((item) => (
                <Picker.Item key={item.value} label={item.label} value={item.value} **textColor={Colors.myColorGold} Color={Colors.myColorGold}** />
            ))
          }
        </Picker>
    )
  }

  ItemPicker.propTypes = {
    ItemOptions: PropTypes.object,
    handleChangeItem: PropTypes.func,
    selectedItemID: PropTypes.number,
    **Color: Colors.myColorGold**,
    **placeholderTextColor: Colors.myColorGold**
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These questions seem to be easy. You could have to find the answers from the official docs.

```
 1- style={styles.myAndroidStyle}
    //you can style your components as follows
  1==> style={{color:'black'}}//for component having one style
  2==> style={styles.myAndroidStyle}//where myAndroidStyle would have all the stylings
  3==> style={[style.myAndroidStyle,{color:'black}]}//where you can combine both the stylings
```

2- `color color={Colors.myColorGold} color: Colors.myColorGold`
I might be wrong in this case but actually it seems as color= and color: is the way styling is provided to the component where Colore.myColorGold has that particular color.

3- `this.props.navigation.navigate('NotificationPreferences');`
Actually this is the correct way to navigate to the particular screen.

```
    this.navigate('NotificationPreferences');
//here it seems as navigate can be defined as follows:
const navigate=this.props.navigation.navigate;
or 
navigate(screen)
{
return this.props.navigation.navigate(screen)}
```

4- I don't think pickers have any kind of placeholders, but rather it only has the text and you can change the text color for it as follows.

```
 itemStyle={{ backgroundColor: "grey", color: "blue", fontFamily:"Ebrima", fontSize:17 }}
```

Comment: style={style.myAndroidStyle,{color:'black}}//where you can combine both the stylings does not work

Comment: it finaly worked but I had to use this format instead ```style={[style.myAndroidStyle,{color:'black}]}```